# Is there anyway to override the 'main' sourceset for jib?

Tags: gradle, jib

For my java plugin I'm using a non-default sourceset. How do I tell jib that's where my source files are? With my gradle file as shown below jib responds with:

```
> Task :jib FAILED
No classes files were found - did you compile your project?
```

I see that jib defaults to 'main' as the sourceset name - is there a way to override that?
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/jib/gradle/GradleProjectProperties.java#L96

```
apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "com.google.cloud.tools.jib"

sourceSets {
  custom {
    java {
      srcDirs = ["src"]
    }
  }
}

jib {
  to {
    image = "foo"
  }
}
```

if I change `custom` to `main` in the above, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin does not give you any option to specify which source set to use. So your only option is to ensure your custom source set is added to `main`:

For example, assuming your custom source set is named `custom`, something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.custom.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.custom.output
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an option I considered, but I had two concerns: one, are there any other attributes of 'java' I need to copy over (besides compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath)? And two, I did not have immediate success with it because the project is actually comprised of many sub-projects and I got the impression I would have to modify their build files as well as the main one. 
But I appreciate the confirmation and I will pursue it further.